# Python-Nmap scan ports by list

Tags: python, nmap

i have try to scan some port in list. I know nmap has support for port scan from file. I'm tried on nmap and that working:

```
nmap 141.101.220.172 -p $(tr '\n' , </home/congminhcpt/donnq/ports.list)
```

but when i'm try to use it on python, some thing has problems with error code in nmap scan result:

```
Error #485: Your port specifications are illegal.
```

That my python code:

```
import json
import nmap

nm = nmap.PortScanner()
arg = '-sV -p $(tr \'\\n\' , </home/congminhcpt/donnq/ports.list)'
data = nm.scan(hosts='141.101.220.172', arguments=arg)
```

this is ports.list file:

```
25
80
110
143
443
```

Hope some one can help me!
Thanks!

Comment: Wait...I think that the parameter -p cant accept a list

Answer (score 0):

The `nmap` python library won't accept the redirection from the file, you'd better list the ports right in the command line, since there are just a few:

```
arg = '-sV -p T:21-25,80,139,8080'  # or whatever ports you want
```

`T:` means you want to scan TCP ports. If you want UDP, put `U` there.

Answer (score 0):

thanks, simple way is convert list to string and scan with `argument='-p ' + port_string`
thanks for help!